# Loop simple function through all worksheets

Tags: loops, excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm attempting to create a macro which performs the following on every Worksheet in a Workbook.

```
Range("U10").Select
    FormulaR1C1 = "=R3C2"
    Range("U10").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("U10:U19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("U10:U19").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("V10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("V10:V19").Select
        Selection.Copy
    Range("U10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("V9:V19").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A16").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
```

I've tried:

```
Sub parse()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

   'The above code

        Next ws

End Sub
```

Unfortunately this appears to be only applying this macro to the current active sheet.

I have a feeling it has to do with my not referring to the range properly (I'm new to VBA so any explanation would really help me with a solution!). Ie. should it be like ws.Range... etc Or should I be doing something entirely different?

Comment: Yes, `ws.Range...` is what you need. It's good practise to always qualify a Range with a worksheet, and in this case it's required. You'll also need to edit your code to remove the `Select`'s, since you can't select a range if the parent sheet is not active.

Answer (score 6):

You're pretty close

```
Sub parse()

Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ws.Range("U10:U19").FormulaR1C1 = "=R3C2"
        ws.Range("U10:U19").Value=ws.Range("U10:U19").value
        ws.Range("A16").ClearContents

    Next ws

End Sub
```

As Tim and Gimp stated, the more you can compress your code, the more efficient and easier to maintain. This includes avoiding `.Select` statements, unneeded operations (like your back and forth to paste values), and others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine them like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .Range("U10").Select
            FormulaR1C1 = "=R3C2"
            .Range("U10").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=.Range("U10:U19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            .Range("U10:U19").Select
            Selection.Copy
            .Range("V10").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            .Range("V10:V19").Select
            Selection.Copy
            .Range("U10").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            .Range("V9:V19").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            .Range("A16").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
        End With
    Next ws
```

Reason is that you need to preface each range reference with what worksheet it should use the range of. you can do this by using `ws.Range().select each time`, or by blocking it all together like I did above..

That being said, you can remove a lot of unnecessary lines in yoru code too, it'll look like this...

```
Sub parse()

Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .Range("U10").FormulaR1C1 = "=R3C2"
            .Range("U10").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("U10:U19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            .Range("U10:U19").Copy
            .Range("V10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            .Range("V10:V19").Copy
            .Range("U10").Paste
            .Range("V9:V19").ClearContents
            .Range("A16").ClearContents
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```